# How to force asset compilation - Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

Using Rails 6.0.2.1 with Ruby 2.6.3 and NGINX
I have a rake task that has the job of re compiling assets when they change in the production server

```
#Called by delayed job UpdateAssetsJob
require 'rake'
desc "Applying Theme, will restart server and may take a while!"

task :apply_css => :environment do
  Rails.logger.info("Applying CSS in #{Rails.env}")
  if Rails.env == "production"
    Rails.logger.info("Compiling Assets")
    Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke
    Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].reenable
  #      `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`
    Rails.logger.info("Cleaning assets - busting cache")
    Rake::Task['assets:clean'].invoke
    Rake::Task['assets:clean'].reenable
  #      `RAILS_ENV="production" rake assets:clean`
    Rails.logger.info("Restarting Puma server")
    `bundle exec pumactl -S /home/app_path/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /home/app_path/shared/puma.rb restart`
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that assets will only ever be compiled once.

I have tried clobbering the assets before compiling using

```
    #Clobber assets to force recompilation
    Rails.logger.info("Clobber Assets")
    Rake::Task['assets:clobber'].invoke
    Rake::Task['assets:clobber'].reenable
```

But again this will only work once

The scenario is:

An administrator updates colours for the current application theme which causes a background task, delayed job, to write necessary changes to

```
assests/stylesheets/_colours.scss file
```

For these changes to take effect I compile the assets, clean the assets, ensuring visitors that have cached assets get the latest version and then restart the server

As I am using the partial syntax for the naming of _colours.scss I have no need for this functionality in the development environment as changes are automatically picked up

Suggestions for a more appropriate solution are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by switching from using

```
Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke
Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].reenable
```

to

`RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`

I do need to clobber the assets and unexplainably the assets:clobber task will run multiple times once I switched the precompile task

Problem solved